# mysql max function in group by

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I try to get items in mysql, I need to remove from result t2 items, that have status_id = 17 and status_change_date less then max date_created for this t1

```
t1:  
-----
|id |
-----
| 1 |
-----


t2:
---------------------------------------------------------------
| id | t1_id | status_change_date | status_id |  date_created | 
---------------------------------------------------------------
|  1 |     1 | 2006-02-12         |        17 |  2004-02-12   | 
|  2 |     1 | 2006-02-12         |        17 |  2006-02-12   | 
|  3 |     1 | 2010-02-12         |        17 |  2007-02-12   | 
|  4 |     1 | 2006-02-12         |        17 |  2008-02-12   | 
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

so in result I should to see only item with id 3, cause only in this case status_change_date is after max date_created for items, that have reference to t1 item with id 1

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.* 
FROM t1 JOIN 
    (
     SELECT t2.*, 
     MAX(date_created) AS max_date FROM t2 WHERE t2.id NOT IN
         (
             SELECT t2.id  FROM t2
             WHERE
                 status_id = 17 
             and status_change_date < max_date
         ) 
     GROUP BY t1_id
    ) t2 ON t1.id = t2.t1_id
```

But i got error cause sql don't know what is max_date. How I should to get this value?

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do with sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation.

Comment: Totally unclear what you are asking.  Please _edit_ your question and show us sample input and the expected output.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I need to remove from result t2 items, that have status_id = 17 and status_change_date less then max date_created for this t1

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen question was edited, I can provide example of input and output if it is unclear now

Comment: Still unclear, or at least would invite speculation.  _Show_ us your data, and then show us the expected output.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I added example, I hope its clear now..

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand of joins, your 'from' should come AFTER your 'select' statements.

```
select *,left(name,1) as L1 from artists order by name limit 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store value to temporary variable and use to compare:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.* 
FROM t1 JOIN 
    (
     SELECT t2.*, 
     @max_date:=MAX(date_created) AS max_date FROM t2 WHERE t2.id NOT IN
         (
             SELECT t2.id  FROM t2
             WHERE
                 status_id = 17 
             and status_change_date < @max_date
         ) 
     GROUP BY t1_id
    ) t2 ON t1.id = t2.t1_id
```

Comment: @sbk  but I think in this case I check max_date for all t2 items and I need max_date for each t2 groups with identical t2_id..

Comment: Please try to use order descending and limit 1 to get join on max_date in subquery.

Comment: can you please get the example?

Comment: i think this should help:

SELECT t1.*, tb2.*
FROM t1 left JOIN 
    (
     SELECT b.* FROM t2 b WHERE 1 group by b.status_change_date having(b.status_change_date >= max(b.date_created)) limit 1
    ) tb2 ON t1.id = tb2.t1_id

Answer (score 0):

You can go with anyone of the following queries:

```
SELECT t1.*, 
       t2.*, 
       Max(date_created) AS max_date 
FROM   t1 
       JOIN t2 
         ON t1.id = t2.t1_id 
WHERE  status_id = 17 
GROUP  BY status_change_date 
HAVING status_change_date > max_date;
```

Or

```
SELECT t1.*, 
       t2.* 
FROM   t1 
       JOIN t2 
         ON t1.id = t2.t1_id 
WHERE  status_id = 17 
       AND status_change_date > (SELECT Max(date_created) 
                                 FROM   t2);
```